# Referencing REST Endpoint by name

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying, in ArcGIS Online specifically, to reference a map service layer by its name as opposed to by its reference ID.  Does anyone know how to do this in the URL?

Comment: You would have to query the service for all the layers and find the index of the one you want. I think ArcRest does this. You could crack open the source code on github and have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Search](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Search/02r3000000mp000000/) API.

- Example:
  http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/search?q=yourname&f=pjson

and parse the json response to find the url of the service.